# How to open Joplin from terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I have just installed [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) on Fedora, by simply using `wget`; more specifically this is waht I typed in my terminal:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurent22/joplin/dev/Joplin_install_and_update.sh | bash
```

All went well and I can now open Joplin by searching it in the Gnome search bar; **however** I would really like to be able to open it from the terminal, instead of having to search it and then opening it by clicking on its icon.

Typing `joplin` on my terminal accomplishes nothing.

How can I set up a terminal command to open Joplin? In Windows, for example, I would add the `.exe` file to the `PATH` variable.. Is there an analogous way on Fedora or GNU/Linux in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will answer my own question here! I realized it's really simple: just make an alias! We can use the search function of our file explorer to find the location of the `.AppImage` of Joplin, and then simply make the corresponding alias; so it's sufficient to simply type into the terminal:

```
alias joplin = "/path/to/joplin/appimage"
```

Done! The next time that we will type `joplin` the app will be launched! Easy as that!

This should work with any other app too!